# Android List View not viewing elements of an array

Tags: java, android

week_forecast array contains the elements that should appear in the design but this didn't happen
what appears is item1,item2,item3,....

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

        ArrayList<String> week_forecast = new ArrayList<String>();
        week_forecast.add("Today - Sunny - 88/630");
        week_forecast.add("Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/46");
        week_forecast.add("Weds - Cloudy - 72/63");
        week_forecast.add("Thurs - Rainy - 64/51");
        week_forecast.add("Fri - Foggy - 70/46");
        week_forecast.add("Sat - Sunny - 76/68");

        // initializing the adapter of the list of views
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.List_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,week_forecast);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```

*listview_forecast is the id of main fragment with the listview

*list_item_forecast is the name of the fragment with the textview

*list_item_forecast_textview is the id of prev fragment

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.List_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,week_forecast);
```

to this

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.List_item_forecast,week_forecast);
```